# Better way to remove characters that aren't ASCII 32 to 175 C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I need to remove characters from a string that aren't in the Ascii range from 32 to 175, anything else have to be removed.

I doesn't known well if RegExp can be the best solution instead of using something like .replace() or .remove() pasing each invalid character or something else.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just remove them with normal string indexing?  The target string can be allocated as the same length as the source string becasue it's guaranted to be the same length or shorter.  Then just copy valid characters in a loop?  It's just two compares to check for valid.

Comment: And another copy of the `char[]` because the string would be the same length as before, just with zero-padding that way.

Comment: 128 to 175 is outside the ASCII range

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use

```
Regex.Replace(myString, @"[^\x20-\xaf]+", "");
```

The regex here consists of a character class (`[...]`) consisting of all characters *not* (`^` at the start of the class) in the range of U+0020 to U+00AF (32–175, expressed in hexadecimal notation). As far as regular expressions go this one is fairly basic, but may puzzle someone not very familiar with it.

But you can go another route as well:

```
new string(myString.Where(c => (c >= 32) && (c <= 175)).ToArray());
```

This probably depends mostly on what you're more comfortable with reading. Without much regex experience I'd say the second one would be clearer.

A few performance measurements, 10000 rounds each, in seconds:

```
2000 characters, the first 143 of which are between 32 and 175
  Regex without +                          4.1171
  Regex with +                             0.4091
  LINQ, where, new string                  0.2176
  LINQ, where, string.Join                 0.2448
  StringBuilder (xanatos)                  0.0355
  LINQ, horrible (HatSoft)                 0.4917
2000 characters, all of which are between 32 and 175
  Regex without +                          0.4076
  Regex with +                             0.4099
  LINQ, where, new string                  0.3419
  LINQ, where, string.Join                 0.7412
  StringBuilder (xanatos)                  0.0740
  LINQ, horrible (HatSoft)                 0.4801
```

So yes, my approaches are the slowest :-). You should probably go with xanatos' answer and wrap that in a method with a nice, clear name. For inline usage or quick-and-dirty things or where performance does not matter, I'd probably use the regex.

Comment: You should use `+` to make it faster

Comment: thanks, the select approach that are a good option, the regex too to analyze it and known more about it.

Comment: wow nice performance test, I see that xanatos one is the best if have to remove characters from a big text, thanks for taking the time to test it, in my case I will remove characters from short string and seems that linq is the way to go for me, not the more performant, not the shorter to write, but easy to apply/write  in a 1 line sentence :) thanks again to you, xanatos and all the users that replied

Comment: Well, performance depends on what you do, how often you do it and where time is spent. For example regex without `+` takes a very long time if there are many characters to remove, on the other hand using StringBuilder takes longer if there are more characters to *append*. Some methods scale with the length of the input string, some with the length of the output string; almost all have very different overheads. Usually my advice is to write what you can read best and worry about performance if it becomes a bottleneck. You probably don't routinely filter semi-large strings 10000 times in a row.

Answer (score 9):

Because I think that if you don't know how to write a Regex you shouldn't use it, especially for something so simple:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var c in str)
{
    if (c >= 32 && c <= 175)
    {
        sb.Append(c);
    }
}

var str2 = str.ToString();
```

Comment: That's what I thought.  A regex call seems a bit OTT for this?

Comment: I have something very similar to this, except an additional section that attempts to transform common high ascii into the low ascii alternative, ie `“` into `"`

Comment: @FabianSilva I don't think the best way to learn something is to go to a board and ask "can you write it for me in a language I don't know?"

Comment: thanks for the advice on not using regExp before learn about it, 
I edited the title to "BETTER WAY to remove characters from a string that not are ascii in c#" to be more clear, 
I speak in spanish and hope that my question be understand well, sorry if this question is annoying for you or any ppl on this board... by asking questions like this (if not found) when I doesn't sure what is the best solution make me to think on new ways to make something that I don't do in the best/efficient way. in this case a linq expression is better. thanks again

Comment: I used if (c >= 01 && c <= 175) to keep the tabs and carriage returns.

Answer (score 3):

Use regex `[^\x20-\xAF]+` and replace it by empty string `""`

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\x20-\xAF]+", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using linq this way

```
string text = (from c in "AAA hello aaaa #### Y world" 
               let i = (int) c where i < 32 && i > 175 select c)
              .Aggregate("", (current, c) => current + c);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, your linq expression is a good solution but seems to me that the joey expression is more easy to understand.

Comment: btw thanks for this alternate solution using let and aggregate

Answer (score 1):

```
static unsafe string TrimRange(string str, char from, char to)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        char ch = str[i];

        if ((ch >= from) && (ch <= to))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
        return String.Empty;

    if (count == str.Length)
        return str;

    char * result = stackalloc char[count];

    count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        char ch = str[i];

        if ((ch >= from) && (ch <= to))
        {
            result[count ++] = ch;
        }
    }

    return new String(result, 0, count);
}
```